# возможно ли сделать пагинацию без переключения главной страницы только через HTML и CSS?

Tags: css3, html5

Ребят подскажите возможно ли вот из этого макета https://www.figma.com/file/JYAvGyQmC2b48xA1uzNiOZLy/Blitz?node-id=0%3A1
сверстать четвертый блок с карточками что бы он корректно работал используя только html и css

И еще один вопрос! почему когда я закидываю сайт на хостинг не все прописанные в css работаю? просматриваю страницу все ок! а закидываю на хостинг сайт кривой половина стилей не работает!
вот так на хостинге выглядит css:http://lincoln01.beget.tech/

А так он на самом деле выглядет!

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Geometria;
    src: url(../fonts/geometria.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Geometria;
    src: url(../fonts/geometria-bold.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    }
body {
    font-family: Geometria, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;

}
.cont {
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
    margin-top: 71px;
    float: left;
}
.menu1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    float: left;
}
.menu:hover {
    background: #DBDAD9;
}
.logo {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 91px
}
.be {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 57px;
    margin-left: 13px;
}
header p {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 58px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: Geometria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.phone {
    float:right;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    
}
.call {
    float: right;
    background: #EEF3FA;
    font-family: Geomeria, serif;
    padding: 16px 55px;
    border: 1px solid #2A94E2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
button:hover {
    background: #2A94E2;

}
.head h1 {
    
width: 580px;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 55px;
font-family: geometria-bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #000000;
padding-top: 30px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.head {
    width: 900px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.par {
    
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #000000;
}
.sp {
    border: solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.flex h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
     font-size: 80px;
     line-height: 131px;
     color: #2A94E2;
     
}
.flex p {

    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #2A94E2;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}
.flex {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    float: left;
}
.glass {


}
.sham {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
    margin-left: -380px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.vin {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.apart {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #EEF3FA;
    font-family: Geomeria, serif;
    padding: 16px 90px;
    border: 1px solid #2A94E2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.double h2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Geometria,serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;

}
.it {
       margin: 0 auto;
       font-family: Geometria;
       font-size: 20px;
       line-height: 36px;
       margin-top: 20px;

}
.double {
    margin: 0 auto;
     width: 930px;
}

.blok{
    display: flex;
    width: 900px;
    height: 350px;
    border: solid #F6F6F6;
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
    position: relative;
}
h4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Geometria serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 70px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.pic {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.pic1 {
        width: 300px;
    height: 170px;
        margin-right: 20px;
}
.picblock {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: Geometria serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 90px;
    width: 75%;
   
}
.blockleft {
    height: 290px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px 0px 70px 30px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F1F1F1;
}
.blockright {
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: flex;
    border-left: 2px solid #F1F1F1;

}
.like {
    
    margin: 40px 0px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 30px;
}

.it2 {
    
        width: 200px;
    font-family: Geometria;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 26px;
align-items: flex-end;
}


.side{
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.answer {

    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50px;
}
.forw {
   display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 17px;
    left: 400px;
}
.vector {
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.next {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #2A94E2;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.next:hover {
      margin-top:-5px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.trouble {
    margin: 0 auto;
     width: 930px;
margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.trouble h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
line-height: 33px;
color: #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
}

.trouble h2 {

font-size: 35px;
line-height: 48px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 60px;
}

.foto {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
height: 900px;
position: relative;
}
.f1 {
    background: url(../img/pic3.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f2 {
    background: url(../img/pic4.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f3{
    background: url(../img/pic5.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.f4 {
    background: url(../img/pic6.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    width: 609px;
    height: 290px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 300px;
    right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.f5 {
    background: url(../img/pic7.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    width: 600px;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.f6 {
    background: url(../img/pic8.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    width: 305px;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cal {
        background: #EEF3FA;
    font-family: Geomeria, serif;
    padding: 16px 80px;
    border: 1px solid #2A94E2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 320px;
    left: 25px;

}

.f1 h3 {
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 33px;
color: #FFFFFF;
position: absolute;
bottom: 450px;
    left: 25px;

}

.f1 p {
margin: 0 auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 38px;
}


.f2 h3 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
}
.f3 h3 {
        bottom: 600px;
    right: 20px;
}

.f4 h3 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
}

.f5 h3 {
bottom: 0;
left: 20px;
}

.f6 h3 {
bottom: 0;
right: 130px;
}










.f1 h3:hover {
    color: #2A94E2;
}

.f2 h3:hover {
    color: #2A94E2;
}
.f3 h3:hover {
    color: #2A94E2;
}
.f4 h3:hover {
    color: #2A94E2;
}
.f5 h3:hover {
    color: #2A94E2;
}
.f6 h3:hover {
    color: #2A94E2;
}

.f1:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f2:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f3:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f4:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f5:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.f6:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.four h2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 35px;
line-height: 48px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 60px;
}
.four p {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: 20px;
}







-------------------------------

ul{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
   text-align: center;
}

#pagination-flickr li{
border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
font-size:16px;
list-style:none;
}
#pagination-flickr a{
border:solid 1px #DDDDDD;


}
#pagination-flickr .previous-off,
#pagination-flickr .next-off {
color:#666666;
display:block;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
padding:3px 4px;
}
#pagination-flickr .next a,
#pagination-flickr .previous a {
font-weight:bold;
border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#pagination-flickr .active{
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #2A94E2;
font-weight:bold;
display:block;
float:left;
padding:4px 6px;
}
#pagination-flickr a:link,
#pagination-flickr a:visited {
color:#0063e3;
display:block;
float:left;
padding: 20px 30px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#pagination-flickr a:hover{
border:solid 1px #666666;
}
```

спасибо заранее!

Comment: Там не пагинация, а фильтр по ценам. А ниже подгрузка новых карточек. Чтобы фильтр верно работал при этом, простого добавления элементов будет мало. Это всё на JS пишется. При клике на плашку цены должен быть запрос на сервер, он возвращает первую порцию уже отфильтрованную, и скрипт меняет контент блока. А при подгрузке внизу у сервера запрашивается следующая порция с тем же фильтром цены.

Comment: блин я надеялся есть выход! джава только учу!) Спасибо!